# Unable To Fetch parameterized value from testNG xml

Tags: selenium, automation, testng, parameterization

**This is the testNG.xml File:**

[image]

**This is the day4.java File**

[image]]

**This is the console Result.**
[image: This is the console Result.]

Why I am getting this issue?

I also tried with @optional method but in the that way I am getting the NULL value.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passed any parameter value in the testng.xml file.Your xml file should look like

```
 <suite name="Parameter test Suite" verbose="1">
        <!-- This parameter will be passed to every test in this suite -->
        <parameter name="suite-param" value="suite level parameter" />
        <test name="Home loan">
            <classes>
                <class name="test">
                    <methods>
                        <include name="demo" />
                    </methods>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </test>
 </suite>
```

Here parameter name and value will be your **URL**

Few more details about xml file
https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/TestNG+-User+specified+TestNG+xml+parameters

Answer (score 0):

So you have to make 2 changes.

Your code should look like this:

`@Parameter("URL")
@Test
public void webloginHomeloan(@Optional String urlname){`

```
System.out.println("WebloginHome");
System.out.println("Parameterized value is:"+ URL)
```

`}`

Add @Optional in parameter as you are not passing any value from String urlname and change "urlname" to "URL"